# I need to rotate some fields on a table

Tags: tables, rotating

How can I align the text `Familia` to the center as in the `Excel table`? Also, how can I space the cell that says `Program Memory`. Look Picture 2. The rotated text looks different.

My code:

```
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Familia} & \rot{\textbf{Fabricante}} & \rot{\textbf{MCU}} & \rot{\textbf{Program Memory}}&\rot{\textbf{EEPROM}} &\rot{\textbf{SRAM}} &\rot{\textbf{I/Os}} &\rot{\textbf{Timers 8-bits}} &\rot{\textbf{Timers 16-bits}} &\rot{\textbf{10-bit ADC}} &\rot{\textbf{12-bit ADC}} &\rot{\textbf{5-bit DAC}} &\rot{\textbf{8-bit DAC}} &\rot{\textbf{CCP/ECCP}} &\rot{\textbf{EUSART}} &\rot{\textbf{MSSP (I2C/SPI)}} &\rot{\textbf{PDIP}} &\rot{\textbf{PMD}} \\\hline
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
   \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \caption{Add caption}
\end{table}%
```

[image: Desired table]
[image: Actual table]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Typographically, the second figure is the best one.

Answer (score 5):

You need only change a bit the macro. A self-explained example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\rot[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\makebox[10em][l]{\bfseries~ #1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \bfseries Familia & \rot{Fabricante} & \rot{MCU} & \rot{Program Memory} &\rot{EEPROM} & \rot{SRAM} &\rot{I/Os} &\rot{Timers 8-bits} &\rot{Timers 16-bits} &\rot{10-bit ADC} &\rot{12-bit ADC} &\rot{5-bit DAC} &\rot{8-bit DAC} &\rot{CCP/ECCP} &\rot{EUSART} &\rot{MSSP (I2C/SPI)} &\rot{PDIP} &\rot{PMD} \\\hline
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
   \end{tabular}%
    \caption{Add caption\label{tab:addlabel}}
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

To limit the height of the rotated cell, making two rotated lines when needed, change the macro to this:

```
\newcommand\rot[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
~\parbox{6.5em}{\raggedright\parindent0pt\bfseries #1}}}
```

For the sake of clarity, I left all the vertical and horizontal lines, but please see some questions about `booktabs` and table styles.

Comment: Do please also exchange the positions of the `\label` and `\caption` statements.

Comment: @Mico I did not notice. Changed!

Answer (score 4):

You asked,

> how can I space the cell that says `Program Memory`?

By "space the cell", I assume you mean pad it with a bit of whitespace at either end. Please advise if this is not your preferred interpretation.

I suggest you change the definition of `\rot` so that it takes one explicit argument, provide the option `origin=c` to `\rotatebox` (as is done in [@Fran's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508238/5001) as well). To add a bit of padding at either end of the cell, I suggest you insert a "kern" (non-breakable, non-discardable whitespace) at the beginning and end of the main argument of `\rotatebox`. In the code below, I've set the padding to `3pt`; you are obviously free to adjust the amount of padding.

Incidentally, since `\rot` and `\textbf` always seem to occur together in your table, you might as well create a macro called, say, `\bfrot` which combines both operations.

A separate comment: If you plan to cross-reference the table elsewhere in the document (generally via a `\ref` statement), the table's `\caption` must come *before*, not after, the `\label` statement.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, a4paper]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage{array}    % for '\extrarowheight' macro

\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\rotatebox' directive
\newcommand*\bfrot[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\bfseries\kern3pt #1\kern3pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} %  optional, for an ever so slightly more "open" look
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{17}{c|}}
\hline
\textbf{Familia} 
&\bfrot{Fabricante}    &\bfrot{MCU} 
&\bfrot{Program Memory}&\bfrot{EEPROM} 
&\bfrot{SRAM}          &\bfrot{I/Os} 
&\bfrot{Timers 8-bits} &\bfrot{Timers 16-bits} 
&\bfrot{10-bit ADC}    &\bfrot{12-bit ADC} 
&\bfrot{5-bit DAC}     &\bfrot{8-bit DAC} 
&\bfrot{CCP/ECCP}      &\bfrot{EUSART} 
&\bfrot{MSSP (I2C/SPI)}&\bfrot{PDIP} 
&\bfrot{PMD} \\
\hline
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j & k & l & m & n & o & p & q & r \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Add caption}\label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```